# Using the superglobal $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php

I need to set a variable using the superglobal `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and want to strip everything before the actual file name.

For example: in referring to a file `http://example.com/public/admin.php`, I need to get only the `admin.php` partion.

Tried searching for `%/admin.php`, at no avail. Which would be a good method for that? Is this too much of a noob question?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different `$_SERVER` value. There are [lots to choose from](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Such as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` :

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  = "admin.php?get=anything&here"

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/admin.php"
```

Or even:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = "/admin.php"
```

`PHP_SELF` should genernally **not be used** due to it taking in any URL variables (`$_GET` values) and so allowing unqualified user submitted data into the `$_SERVER` var.

For example `admin.php?get=anything&script=instructions`.

Comment: Hmmm. Seems to me that 'SCRIPT_NAME' will do the trick for me, did not know about it. Will test and come back if needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FabioRosa if it worked can you tick m answer and give it +1 thanks `:-)`